# Solve a linear equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have this equations

$$x+3y+6z=3$$
$$x+y+z=-2$$
$$-x+y+4z=7$$

my solution is

$$x=0$$
$$y=-5$$
$$z=3$$

this task is 1 of 3 and there is going to be 1 that can be solved, 1 that will have a solution with rational numbers and the last 1 wont have any solution. This last one wont have any solution but I have one.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Could it be because there are more than 1 solution for each of x, y and z? For instance, $x = 3$, $y = -10$ and $z = 5$ also fits.

Comment: The $3$ equations are *not actually independent* from each other, because if we subtract the second equation from the first, we get $2y+5z=5$
and if we add the last two equations we get the same equation. This implies that we have 3 unknowns but only 2 independent equations.

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit removing the tag "linear-algebra" and adding the tag "system-of-equations", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2004294).

Answer (score 3):

As via [Cramer's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html),
$D=\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 6 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}=0,$

there will be a family of solutions

From the first two equations,

$$x+3y+6z-3=0$$ 
$$x+y+z+2=0$$

Solving for $x,y$ we get $x=\frac{3z-9}2,y=\frac{5-5z}2$

Putting the values of $x,y$ in the third equation, $$-\frac{3z-9}2+\frac{5-5z}2+4z=7\implies 7=7$$

$$\text{So, } x=\frac{3z-9}2,y=\frac{5-5z}2,z=z$$ will satisfy the given three equations for any finite value of $z$

In your case, $z=3$ and for Jerry, $z=5$